# selected item deleting with the rest of list in custom listview trouble

Tags: android, listview, sharedpreferences

My custom listview row has remove button. I'm trying to delete specific item in listview with this remove button. (Remove from favorites action). I can delete selected item but rest of the list (items under the selected item) deleting with it. Top part still stay. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

**FavoriteListAdapter :**

```
public class FavoritesListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Activity context;
    private List<String> radioName;
    private List<String> listenerNumbers;

    public FavoritesListAdapter(Activity context, List<String> radioName, List<String> listenerNumbers) {
        super(context, R.layout.custom_favorites_listview, radioName);

        this.context=context;
        this.radioName=radioName;
        this.listenerNumbers=listenerNumbers;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        View r= convertView;
        FavoritesViewHolder viewHolder = null;

        if (r == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater= context.getLayoutInflater();
            r= layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_favorites_listview,null,true);
            viewHolder = new FavoritesViewHolder(r);
            r.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        else {
            viewHolder = (FavoritesViewHolder) r.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.row_tv_favorites_radio_name.setText(radioName.get(position));
        viewHolder.row_img_favorites_radio_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.radio_logo_renkli);
        viewHolder.row_tv_favorites_listener_numbers.setText("Listeners : " + listenerNumbers.get(position));

        viewHolder.button_remove_from_favorites_list.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                listenerNumbers.remove(position);
                radioName.remove(position);

                SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
                final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.remove("radio_link"+ position);
                editor.remove("radio_name" + position);
                editor.remove("listener_number" + position);
               // editor.clear();
                editor.commit();
               // FavoritesFragment.radio_name_list.remove(position);
               // FavoritesFragment.radio_link_list.remove(position);
               // FavoritesFragment.listener_numbers.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return r;

    }

    class FavoritesViewHolder {
        TextView row_tv_favorites_radio_name;
        TextView row_tv_favorites_listener_numbers;
        ImageView row_img_favorites_radio_icon;
        Button button_remove_from_favorites_list;
        FavoritesViewHolder(View v) {
            row_tv_favorites_radio_name= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_radio_name_favorites);
            row_tv_favorites_listener_numbers = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_listener_numbers_favorites);
            row_img_favorites_radio_icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_radio_icon_favorites);
            button_remove_from_favorites_list = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.remove_favorites_from_list_button);
        }
    }

}
```

**In my PlayRadioFragment, users have add favorite button, and values sent FavoritesFragment with unique keys**

```
 public static int incrementedValue = 0;



     SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

        add_favorites_button= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.add_favorites_button);
        add_favorites_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                editor.putString("radio_link"+ incrementedValue, radio_play_link);
                editor.putString("radio_name" + incrementedValue, radio_name);
                editor.putString("listener_number" + incrementedValue, listener_number);
               // editor.clear();
                editor.commit();

                incrementedValue++;
            }

        });
```

**And this is my FavoritesFragment :**

```
public class FavoritesFragment extends Fragment {



    public static FavoritesListAdapter adapter_2;

    public FavoritesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    TextView radio_name_txt, radio_link_txt;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view=  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favorites, container, false);


        final List<String> radio_name_list = new ArrayList<>();
        final List<String> radio_link_list = new ArrayList<>();
        final List<String> listener_numbers = new ArrayList<>();



        for (int i=0; i<Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
            SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PREFS",0);
            String radio_name = settings.getString("radio_name" +i, "");
            String radio_link = settings.getString("radio_link" +i, "");
            String listener_number = settings.getString("listener_number" +i, "");

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(radio_name)){break;}
            else {radio_name_list.add(radio_name);}

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(radio_link)){break;}
            else {radio_link_list.add(radio_link);}

            listener_numbers.add(listener_number);
        }



        PlayRadioFragment.incrementedValue = radio_name_list.size();

        ListView listView_favorites = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview_favorites);
        adapter_2 = new FavoritesListAdapter(getActivity(), radio_name_list, listener_numbers);
        listView_favorites.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                PlayRadioFragment fragment= new PlayRadioFragment();
                Bundle bundle= new Bundle();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                bundle.putString("radio_play_links", radio_link_list.get(position));
                bundle.putString("radio_name", radio_name_list.get(position));
                bundle.putString("listener_number", listener_numbers.get(position));
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout,fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

            }
        });
        listView_favorites.setAdapter(adapter_2);



        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to delete item or remove it from favourites?

Comment: It would be great, but I could not made that way. So I'm trying delete selected favorite on listview.

Comment: Can you use Object class Please it will make work easier

Comment: I'm new on Android, I don't know how to use it. If it takes not long time, can you show me on my codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Your Object class As:

```
public class DemoGson {

    private  String radio_link,radio_name,listener_number;

    public String getRadio_link() {
        return radio_link;
    }

    public void setRadio_link(String radio_link) {
        this.radio_link = radio_link;
    }

    public String getRadio_name() {
        return radio_name;
    }

    public void setRadio_name(String radio_name) {
        this.radio_name = radio_name;
    }

    public String getListener_number() {
        return listener_number;
    }

    public void setListener_number(String listener_number) {
        this.listener_number = listener_number;
    }
}
```

While Adding data to it create new object and add data then insert that particular object to arraylist and pass arraylist to your adapter

```
ArrayList<DemoGson> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        DemoGson demoGson = new DemoGson();
        demoGson.setRadio_link("yourlink");
        demoGson.setRadio_name("yourname");
        demoGson.setListener_number("2");

        arrayList.add(demoGson);
```

and then

```
  adapter_2 = new FavoritesListAdapter(getActivity(),arrayList);
```

and in adapter just remove position from your arraylist

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't  not remove element from the adapter, only from your custom arrays:

```
 listenerNumbers.remove(position);
 radioName.remove(position);
```

In additional, you need to remove the item from the internal ArrayList of the adapter. Do it like this:

```
remove(getItem(position));
```

Generally, it is not good approach to manage 2 parallel custom arrays in the adapter (listenerNumbers, radioName in your case). Better to define Item class, containing both those fields, and provide ArrayList of the objects of this class to adapter as parameter (instead of array of Strings like in your case).  And also o implement supporting XML for the item, that will have both items (TextView and RadioButton).

Comment: I also  tried remove elements from adapter's Arraylist.            
   // FavoritesFragment.radio_name_list.remove(position);
               // FavoritesFragment.radio_link_list.remove(position);
               // FavoritesFragment.listener_numbers.remove(position). But it's not solution for my main problem, So, looks like I have to try other methods. Thanks

Comment: Again, removing items from array will not remove them from adapter.
What I suggested above - is running internal method of adapter. It's also called remove, but it accepts the object itself, not the index/position. Lets do it in two lines:
String remItem = getItem(position);
remove(remItem);

hope it clarifies the issue.